# Find names that have an "r" in any position past the second position

Tags: sql

I want to find names that have an "r" in any position past the second position

```
SELECT names 
FROM Workers
WHERE names LIKE (??r    -------The name can have 22 characters though.
```

Comment: Tag RDBMS you use, because some of them don't support regex

Comment: @Shnugo Check https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/392579  `WHERE names LIKE '__%r%'`

Comment: @lad2025: that would return `'rrr'` as well but the 'r' should be after the second position.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes it returns as well.  OP does not say it couldn't do so

Comment: @lad2025: the question is: "*any position **past** the second*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry but I do not treat this like you. I would wait for OP clarification

Comment: @Tucker Should `Raror` be returned as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can `SUBSTRING` string first and then use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT names 
FROM Workers 
WHERE SUBSTRING(names, 3, LENGTH(names) - 2) LIKE '%r%';
  -- AND NOT LEFT(names, 2) LIKE '%r%'; --if "Raror" should not be returned
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6f985/3/0)**</kbd>

The best way is to use `REGEX` but not every database support it. Below `MySQL` version:

```
SELECT names 
FROM Workers 
WHERE names RLIKE '^.{2}.*r.*$';
 -- names RLIKE '^[^rR]{2}.*r.*$'; --if "Raror" should not be returned
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6f985/5/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres:

```
select *
from workers
where strpos(names ,'r') > 2
```